# Find the sum of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \ln\left[1 - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2}\right]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \ln\left[1 - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2}\right]$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Also, please type your question rather than posting a link to an image since links can get broken and images may not be readable by users who rely on screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

The series
$=\ln(1-\frac{1}{4})+\ln(1-\frac{1}{9})+\ln(1-\frac{1}{16})+\ln(1-\frac{1}{25})+...$

$=\ln[(\frac{3}{4})(\frac{8}{9})(\frac{15}{16})(\frac{24}{25})...]$

$=\ln[(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 2})(\frac{2 \cdot 4}{3 \cdot 3})(\frac{3\cdot 5}{4 \cdot 4})(\frac{4 \cdot 6}{5 \cdot 5})...]$

I stop here, you can cancel out the fraction and find the answer.

Comment: can you solve using limit comparison please

Comment: Why? limit comparison test usually is used to show that limit converge or limit diverge.